# PowerShell replacing with wrong symbol

Tags: powershell, csv, replace

I'm trying to replace `£` characters in a CSV with `GBP`.

I created a test CSV (C:\test\test1) as follows:

```
col1,
£100 Test
```

I have managed to write the following code:

```
Import-Csv C:test\test1.csv |
    ForEach { if($_.ou -match "£") {$_.OU = $_.OU -replace "£","GBP"}; $_} |
    Export-Csv C:\test\test1replaced.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My issue is that in the file created the `£` symbol seems to be replaced with `?` and not `GBP`. Can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `-Encoding UTF8`.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the answer of Jeroen Mostert:

Replace :

```
Import-Csv C:test\test1.csv |
ForEach { if($_.ou -match "£") {$_.OU = $_.OU -replace "£","GBP"}; $_} |
Export-Csv C:\test\test1replaced.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

With this:

```
Import-Csv C:test\test1.csv -Encoding UTF8 |
ForEach { if($_.ou -match "£") {$_.OU = $_.OU -replace "£","GBP"}; $_} |
Export-Csv C:\test\test1replaced.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You should use the *-Encoding* Switch and set the type as UTF8 to get it done.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. If I run:     Import-Csv C:test\test1.csv -Encoding UTF8  its already converting the character in the console to  
�

Comment: If I run -Encoding Default the symbol appears correctly in the console but then the replace doesn't then work

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks for the input. It doesn't look like it but it got me to what I came up with:

```
(get-content C:test\test1.csv).replace('£', 'GBP') | set-content C:\test\test1replaced.csv
```

Comment: `-join (Get-Content "C:test\test1.csv" -Encoding Byte | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ })` should correctly handle all characters like `£` _Pound Sign_  but it could fail e.g. for `€` _Euro sign_.